# How can I change other clients variable in Unity Photon multiplayer?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon, unity-networking

I'm a bit confused with the PunRpc calls, I tried the PhotonTarget.Others to see if it would do health--; on other client, but it didn't work.

At the moment I want to know how I could do health--; on other client when I press space.

This is what i have tried:
this is the command:

```
photonView.RPC("healthReduction", PhotonTargets.Others, null);
```

and this is the RPC

```
    [PunRPC]
void healthReduction()
{
    health--;
    Debug.Log("Health--");
}
```

but it still wont work.

Comment: do you have some code of your Player script?

Comment: Is anything in your log? PUN outputs errors if method does not exist or 
parameters do not match.
You do not log RPC call. Are you sure that it gets called?
See PUN demos for RPC usage samples.

Comment: The thing is that with the RPC call, I can't reduce ENEMYS health, I can only reduce my health. And so when I call PhotonTargets.Others it will execute the code on MY player, but only others can see the updated health of my player and I can't. I want to execute this code on ENEMY'S player, but now I believe it's not possible with RPC calls, it's only possible to update your own variables so the others can see them, but to get an enemy's variable and modify it is not possible I believe :/ .

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using an Instance and using 2 different named scripts, for example if I want to access PlayerManager1 script from PlayerManager, I do this `PlayerManager1.Instance.photonView.RPC("reduceMyHealth",PhotonTargets.All,null)`

this will call the reduceMyHealth() PunRpc in PlayerManager1.

and to do this you have to add this code to the script you want to access:
`static public PlayerManager1 Instance;` and in start(){}`Instance = this;`

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to solve, I think.
The source code is following as above.

```
public class TestPhoton : Photon.PunBehaviour
{
    public PhotonView gameView;

    void Start()
    {
        gameView = this.GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    }

    public void OnClickTest()
    {
        photonView.RPC("HealthReduction", PhotonTargets.Others);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void HealthReduction()
    {
        health--;
    }
}
```